# crystal report prints blank page at end

Tags: c#-4.0, printing, crystal-reports, epson

[image]
This issue is driving me crazy. 
I am using

> EPSON TM-T88V printer

to print , earlier it was fine one night OS upgraded to WIN10 and it went all crazy. I have a POS for a retaurant, so if I print a bill for a paricular table for the first time it prints with blank page after the bill hence its too long. But again I print it prints perfectly. Called EPSON and had some issues with test page so they some how fixed it , as there support were limited to only test page so left there. When I tried on POS its same.

Heres my code for printing

```
private void BillReceipt_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {

            string sqlqry = "Select tb.TableNo,Pax,WaiterName,ItemCode,ItemName,Quantity,Amount,tb.BillNo,OrderType,RoundOffAmount as RoundOff, Discount,Gratuity,dues,Date1,tb.Time,ModeOfPayment,CardNo,CardHolderName,BankName,TotalAmount,VAT,ServiceTax,AmountPaid,Comments as comment,CustomerName,offeramount,DeliveryTax,Phoneno,Address From tblOrder o,tblBilling tb Where tb.KOTNo=@kotno  and tb.KOTNo=o.KOTNo and o.KOTcancel='False'and o.Quantity>'0'and KOTCancel='False'";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlqry, connectionclass.con);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@kotno", NewOrderBL.KOTNo);
            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataSet3 ds = new DataSet3();
            adapter.Fill(ds, "Billing");
            if (ds.Tables["Billing"].Rows.Count == 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("No Data Found", this.Text, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            }
            if (deliverybl.order == "Delivery")
            {
                PrintBillDelivery printbilldelivery = new PrintBillDelivery();
                printbilldelivery.SetDataSource(ds);
                crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = printbilldelivery;
                System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument printDocument = new System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument();
                printbilldelivery.PrintOptions.PrinterName = printDocument.PrinterSettings.PrinterName;

                printbilldelivery.PrintOptions.PrinterName = "EPSON TM-T88V Receipt";//for JAPNA PC
                printbilldelivery.PrintToPrinter(1, false, 0, 0);

            }
            else
            {
                PrintBillReceipt2 printbillreceipt2 = new PrintBillReceipt2();
                printbillreceipt2.SetDataSource(ds);
                crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = printbillreceipt2;
                System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument printDocument = new System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument();
                printbillreceipt2.PrintOptions.PrinterName = printDocument.PrinterSettings.PrinterName;

                printbillreceipt2.PrintOptions.PrinterName = "EPSON TM-T88V Receipt";//for JAPNA PC
                printbillreceipt2.PrintToPrinter(1, false, 0, 0);

            }


           //////////////////////////////////////////////////
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, this.Text, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }
        finally { connectionclass.disconnect(); }
        NewOrderBL.KOTNo = string.Empty;
        onlinebl.crystalreport = "";
        this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
        // this.Close();
    }
```

If you need any other info do let me know.So please help. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the issue it was because of the WIN 10, once I was able to revert back to WIN 8 it worked as before.
Reason I think was crystal report version 13.x is not compatible with WIN 10(not sure though)